# Cannot OCR in Office 365 Pro Plus Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-onenote

I have Office 365 Pro Plus from work. The install goes without chance to select what you want to have. It installs everything. Its a known "feature".

Normally I would select OCR component during the install.

But not in this product.

I need to OCR an image. In older version I would paste the image into OneNote and there would be a context menu to extract text out of image.

Now there is nothing for it.

**Could someone please advise - is OCR cut out of the 365 Pro Plus or I have to somehow "activate" it?**

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Office.com's website [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Extract-text-from-pictures-and-file-printouts-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-e633bd8f-0b97-4fb4-96e1-0f081541e52e).

To extract text from a single picture you’ve added into OneNote:

1. Right-click the picture, and choose Copy Text from Picture.
2. Place the cursor where you’d like to paste the copied text, and then press Ctrl+V.

It appears that it is now built into Office 2013/2016.

Comment: no its not.. the "Copy Text from Picture" does not exist in my copy of the Office.. this is why I asked.

Comment: @RMarkwald is correct it is present in OneNote that is part of the Pro Plus package for Windows Desktop.  If you are on a Mac I'm not sure if that feature is present.  It is also not available thru the web version, nor the Windows 10 app.